# How to facilitate 2 way 'client' 'server' socket communication

Tags: python, c#, sockets

I'm refactoring/rewriting someone elses old communication layer simply because it is hard to work with and and is full of redundency issues.

**One computer** (Entity 1 / **E1**) needs to communicate with **multiple computers** (Entities 2 / **E2's**) on the same local network.

E1 should be able to send requests to each E2.
An E2 should be able to send requests to the E1.

The E2's uses debian, and runs python code.
The E1 runs windows and C# with wpf.

I have worked with software that uses HTTP servers and socket programming.

My thought process:

1. Establish a socket connection with E1 as the listener, and use the socket to send stuff and receive stuff and just kind of fix propblems like bus contention, concurrency, transaction logic, responses as I see fit.

   - This is what is currently going on.
2. Let a socket listen on the E1 and each E2. The reason for this is because I thaught that the software that listens is supposed to act like a 'server', where server meant receiving requests, processing the request and responding on the request.
3. I figured that after the connection was established, either E1 and E2 can be labeled as a server/client as both can use .send() or .receive() so why not listen with 2 sockets on 2 ports on the E1, let the E2's connect, and dedicate one socket for sending requests and one for receiving requests.

Should I be using sockets?
Is this the right way to go about issueing commands in both directions?
Where is my reasoning going wrong?

Comment: You can definitely use sockets. I'd recommend using either gRPC or possibly signalr if your environments can work with it. Both are fairly easy to setup and you can have working examples of servers communicating rather quickly. Both have c# solutions.

Comment: Better to use a higher level protocol rather than raw sockets, unless absolute performance is key